# Periodicity of calendar

Tags: calendar-computations

Let $A$ be the set of days in week, $A = \{Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu,Fri,Sat,Sun\}$, and $B = \{1,2,\dots,31\}$. For each date, we have a pair $(x,y)$, $x \in A$ and $y \in B$. Then we will have an infinite sequence of these pairs. For example, starting from today (Friday, April 27, 2012), we have $(Fri,27), (Sat,28), (Sun,29),\dots$ and so on. Now my questions are:

1. What is the smallest period $T$ after which the sequence repeats? I know that in every 400 years there are 146097 days, which is a multiple of 7, therefore 146097 is a period. But does there exist a smaller period?
2. During each period $T$, what is (are) the pair (pairs) that appear the most (i.e. highest frequency)? What is the frequency of $(Fri,13)$?

Edit: we are using the [Gregorian calendar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar), with different lengths of months, leap years, etc.

Comment: Are we working on an actual calender, where we have different lengths of months, leap years, etc? Or do you want to know how long it takes to get a repeat if you just consider months of length 31?

Comment: There is no smaller period than $400$, because of the special rule about leap year in years divisible by $100$.

Comment: @AlexBecker: I've just edited the questions to address your comment.

Comment: This table should answer the second part of the question: [http://www.merlyn.demon.co.uk/freq-tbl.txt](http://www.merlyn.demon.co.uk/freq-tbl.txt).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The table at http://www.merlyn.demon.co.uk/freq-tbl.txt gives the frequencies for each the days of the year over the minimum period, which is 400 years.    Several days share the maximum frequency, including Friday the 13th (688/146097).

Comment: The link is no longer valid.

Comment: Here is a similar table. Link is valid as of 8/11/2022: https://x42.com/datelab/daydist.shtml